# DevExpress buttons redraw problem

Tags: winforms, devexpress

Help me please.

I have a stange behaviour. Sometimes, when I'm shitching between tabs in my besktop application, I face a problem with buttons repainting (refreshing) (the lable are not presented on the button). But the button redraws when I move the mouse on it.

[image]

Does anyone know the reason of this behaviour and how to fix it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Buggy third party controls don't surprise me anymore. What's wrong with the built-in options? They have the added bonus of actually looking *native* and blending in with all of the other similar controls on the user's computer, including those in other applications. They don't have any of the buggy behavior, and they're instantly easier to use.

Comment: @Cody: when standard controls provided by the Framework will offer the same features then we will talk again about this... for now, I can't imagine to make a professional application without XtraGrid or XtraEditors... plain DataGrids have 1% only of the features of professional components... if you don't like non native UI this can always be disabled and controls can still look native with skins disabled... keep in mind that also MS in Office 2007 and 2010 is using skins as the Ribbon control native really does not work!

Comment: @Davide: Keep in mind that you're not Microsoft Office, and that there are tons of people who find its UI anywhere from impossible or difficult to use. Lots of large companies are not upgrading from older versions precisely because of the sky-high training costs and the minimal benefits. I've never in my life used an XtraGrid or XtraEditor control, and I've worked on many professional applications and seen many others. Generally, controls don't need "features". They need to be functional. The DevExpress controls and all the others do *not* look native, even with themes disabled.

Comment: @Cody:  Our controls are functional.  Really.  They will look native if you turn off skins.  I would suggest that you try them, perhaps, you will like the functionality embedded and change your own opinion about our controls.  Or, you can create a single form using XtraGrid and XtraEditors and then compare it with the same form built using standard controls.  Also, give your clients a chance to compare both forms look&feel and their functionality.  I eager to hear their opinion.  Here is the link to the trial version: [DXperience](https://www.devexpress.com/ClientCenter/Downloads/#Trials)

Comment: @DevExpress: I've tried them. They're seriously awful. Every client I've ever had would reject them outright. They don't behave like native controls. That's simply unacceptable. And turning off skins and themes doesn't make them look like native controls. It makes them look like they're poorly attempting to *simulate* native controls. That's not the same thing. Moreover, given the number of questions I see on here that complain about buggy behavior with third-party controls, I'm hardly willing to tether myself to them, even if they *did* behave like native controls.

Comment: @Cody, if I do not ask too much, can you try to install our controls and create two forms as I asked before.  I know that our customers like our controls look and feel, like skins (I personally prefer flat and no skins :)).  Just compare ...  Also, you told that "They don't behave like native controls."  Could you please clarify your idea?

Comment: @Cody, about buggy controls.  Take a look at the connect, it is overfull with bugs.  I personally hate this argument, and did not want to post it here, but, to be fair:  standard controls are also buggy.

Answer (score 1):

Which versions of our controls are you using?  I remember, there was a problem with SimpleButton painting but it was resolved in the last (11.1) version.  Can you install this Suite version, upgrade your application and check how it works?

Comment: Thanks for solution. I'll verify it after update. But our next update of DevExpress suite is going to be in October-November... :/